# Writing doxygen documentation in org-mode

Tags: c++, emacs, markdown, doxygen, org-mode

Since version 1.8.0, `doxygen` [supports](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) `markdown`. For people who are used to `org-mode`, the option of writing in `org-mode` and [exporting to `markdown`](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Markdown-export) might be attractive. Since `markdown` implemented by `doxygen` slightly [differs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) from the standard `markdown`, I would like to ask: has anyone tried this workflow? What should one keep in mind when writing documentation this way?